# Replace/Remove specific HTML pattern/string from a source string

Tags: c#, html

I have multiple string values where HTML tags get concatenated to it as highlighted in the below code.

```
"produce single words that are meaningful in <span class='tooltip-low-high'>LOW<span class='tooltiplowhightext'><b>Low demand situations</b> are defined as verbal interactive situations where communication demands are reduced (e.g., familiar setting, familiar conversation partner, known context).</span></span> demand situations?"
```

I need to remove the HTML tag of this pattern but capture the value "LOW" hidden between them such that my final string value should be

```
produce single words that are meaningful in LOW demand situations?
```

I tried with the below code but its not working for some reason, any help is much appreciated

```
 string html = "produce single words that are meaningful in <span class='tooltip-low-high'>LOW<span class='tooltiplowhightext'><b>Low demand situations</b> are defined as verbal interactive situations where communication demands are reduced (e.g., familiar setting, familiar conversation partner, known context).</span></span> demand situations?";
        string alpha = html.Replace(html.Substring(html.IndexOf("<", 0, html.Length), html.IndexOf(">", 0, html.Length)), "");
        string beta = html.Replace(html.Substring(0, alpha.IndexOf("<", 0, alpha.LastIndexOf(">", 0, alpha.Length))), "");
        Console.WriteLine("Final string value  " + beta);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable using simple math of finding X(replacement string) and using that in the replace statement to remove them. Here is the below code.

```
        string str = null;
        str = "produce single words that are meaningful in <span class='tooltip-low-high'>LOW<span class='tooltiplowhightext'><b>Low demand situations</b> are defined as verbal interactive situations where communication demands are reduced (e.g., familiar setting, familiar conversation partner, known context).</span></span> demand situations?";

    int a = str.IndexOf("<", 0, str.Length);
    int b = str.IndexOf(">", 0, str.Length);
    string beta = str.Substring(a,(b-a)+1 );
    string alpha = str.Replace(beta, "");

    int c = alpha.IndexOf("<",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int d = alpha.LastIndexOf(">",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    string gamma = alpha.Substring(c, (d - c) + 1);
    string FinalExtract = alpha.Replace(gamma, "");
    Console.WriteLine(FinalExtract);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
return Regex.Replace(yourString, $"<(.|\n|{Environment.NewLine})*?>", String.Empty);
```

this regex.replace removes anything that lies within "<" and ">"

Comment: Thanks but this is not the result I needed. I already tried this method.. Yes it does remove the anything used under <>, please note the result output in the description.

Comment: you need to remove "Low" right after span tag closure?

Comment: I need to remove this {<span class='tooltip-low-high'> }first and leave "LOW" string and then remove   {<span class='tooltiplowhightext'><b>Low demand situations</b> are defined as verbal interactive situations where communication demands are reduced (e.g., familiar setting, familiar conversation partner, known context).</span></span>}

Comment: I suggest you to use HtmlAgilityPack, which is a library you can find on nuget that can parse the Html and lets you navigate the DOM and check node types (tag / text) tag name, attributes and so on.
You won't be able to do this with just Regex and Replaces.
https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: thanks... not sure whether that would work too... this not an HTML string ...